# Two identical geography objects produce different STIntersects results in SQL Server 2019

Tags: intersection, sql-server, well-known-text, nettopologysuite

Consider I have two POLYON `geography` object, `@g1` and `@g2`. One from WKT and the other one converted from binary:

```
DECLARE @g1 geography = 'POLYGON ((-45.70072144031528 70.79588950876575,-45.70072144031528 -32.671894242015554,202.6781848096847 -32.671894242015554,202.6781848096847 70.79588950876575,-45.70072144031528 70.79588950876575))'
DECLARE @g2 geography = CONVERT(sys.geography,0xE610000001040500000038D88CDAEFB251404CE17A3DB1D946C0ECE969A1005640C04CE17A3DB1D946C0ECE969A1005640C0AC47A1B0B355694038D88CDAEFB25140AC47A1B0B355694038D88CDAEFB251404CE17A3DB1D946C001000000020000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000003)
```

SQL Server reports they are equal if I execute the following query:

```
SELECT @g1.STEquals(@g2) G1EqualsG2
```

```
| G1EqualsG2 |
| ---------- |
| 1          |
```

Now consider I have the following LINESTRING object:

```
DECLARE @line geography
SET @line=CONVERT(geography,0xE610000001040700000022625E9DF79F3D40E89D984C229E5A402D625EED3DA03D403C9E98C81E9E5A400C625E2C86A03D40F39D08B8199E5A4091625E9CBBA03D4055A00808069E5A4033625EFCE2A03D400E9E0828F59D5A4083625E7C26A13D408C9F08F0F09D5A405A625EDC7AA13D409F9E0834E99D5A4001000000010000000001000000FFFFFFFF0000000002)
```

If I try to create intersections for `@line` with `@g1` and `@g2`, I get two identical intersections:

```
SELECT @g1.STIntersection(@line) G1Intersection,
       @g2.STIntersection(@line) G2Intersection,
       @g2.STIntersection(@line).STEquals(@g1.STIntersection(@line)) IntersectionsEqual
```

```
| G1Intersection     | G2Intersection      | IntersectionsEqual |
| ------------------ | ------------------- | ------------------ |
| 0xE610000001040... | 0xE610000001040...  | 1                  |
```

But, if I check whether `@line` intersects with `@g1` and `@g2` using `STIntersects`, I get different result:

```
SELECT @line.STIntersects(@g1) IntersectsG1,
       @line.STIntersects(@g2) IntersectsG2
```

```
| InsersectsG1 | InsersectsG2 |
| ------------ | ------------ |
| 1            | 0            |
```

I'm totally confused here. Why does `STIntersects` produce different result for a LINESTRING with two identical POLYGONs, while they can produce identical intersections?

Can anyone shed some light on this?

---

### Edit

You may have noticed that several longitude values in the code are greater that 180°. It's because I'm using EFCore+NTS to perform query from client, and NTS performs counter-clockwise check on POLYGONs before sending the query.

But it seems that NTS performs this check on a planar coordinate system. It only works when longitude value does not jump across 180° meridian.

In the above case, if I perform the query with orignal longitude value (-157.3218151903153°), NTS will throw an error complaining that my polygon is not counter-clockwise.

To work around this issue, I have to add 360° to longitude values on the right hand side.

This is supposed to work in SQL Server, and as you can see from the example above, it actually works if I create the polygon from WKT. So this comes back to my original question again, why does `STIntersects` produce different result for a LINESTRING with two identical POLYGONs?

Answer (score 2):

It may be a wrong assumption that WKT and WKB are identical. Computing with floating point numbers is inaccurate.

Here is a test made with PostGIS

```
select ST_AsText(
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON ((-45.70072144031528 70.79588950876575,-45.70072144031528 -32.671894242015554,202.6781848096847 -32.671894242015554,202.6781848096847 70.79588950876575,-45.70072144031528 70.79588950876575))'
)
);
```

Compare the source WKT and WKT that comes back from the WKB and see the difference in the last decimals.

`'POLYGON ((-45.70072144031528 70.79588950876575,-45.70072144031528 -32.671894242015554,202.6781848096847 -32.671894242015554,202.6781848096847 70.79588950876575,-45.70072144031528 70.79588950876575))'`

`'POLYGON((-45.7007214403153 70.7958895087658,-45.7007214403153 -32.6718942420156,202.678184809685 -32.6718942420156,202.678184809685 70.7958895087658,-45.7007214403153 70.7958895087658))'`

Perhaps SQL Server reports that geometries are identical because they are as identical as they can be, but some functions do not take into account the floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: I agree your point on floating point numbers. Parsing coordinates from WKT can introduce error. But the difference is small enough to be safely ignored in my situation (3.38706906236313E-08 meters in your example). Both polygons still intersect with the line string I defined in OP. I think the cause of the problem lies in STIntersects.

Comment: Right. It may not be easy to make a bug report https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-get-help?view=sql-server-ver15 but try UserVoice.